# Rendering html using javascript and code from markdown and django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, markdown

I'm trying to create a two column html page that uses django as a manager for a blog. The body of the post has a TextField that is converted to markdown and sent to the html:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=67, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    body_md = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    def save(self):
        selft.body_md = markdown2.markdown(body, extras=['fenced-code-blocks'])
```

Then in the template body post is called:

```
{{ body_md|safe }}
```

That works correctly. However I'm trying to pass the body text to a javascript function that splits the text in two columns and renders it automatically in the html page respecting some boundaries. For example the text in both columns may have a width of 300px and a height of 800px.

The first problem I'm facing is that I can not render the text with javascript when using the markdown field. If I use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = "<div class='row'>" +
"<div class='content'> {{ body_md|safe }}</div>" +
"</div>";
document.write(html);
</script>
```

it doesn't work. However, if instead of using a text processed with markdown like {{ body_md|safe }}, I use something not processed, like the title, {{title}}. Then it renders correctly.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having here is that `safe` is causing Django to print `body_md` (new lines and all) inside what you hoped would be Javascript.

So to be clear you are hope to get:

```
var html = "<div class='row'>" +
"<div class='content'><p>this is the first line</p>" +
"<p>this is the second line</p>" +
"</div>" +
"</div>";
```

but you're actually getting

```
var html = "<div class='row'>" +
"<div class='content'><p>this is the first line</p>
<p>this is the second line</p>
</div>" +
"</div>";
```

which isn't valid javascript. (tip, right click, view page source).

The easiest solution is to do:

```
<div id="hidden_body" style="display: none">{{ body_md|safe }}</div>
<script>
var hidden_body = document.getElementById("hidden_body").innerHTML;
var html = "<div class='row'>" +
"<div class='content'>" + hidden_body + "</div>" +
"</div>";
document.write(html);
```

By the way markdown2 is very slow, [misaka](http://misaka.61924.nl/) is a great option instead.